# brackets in equation environment (XeLaTeX)

Tags: equations, amsmath, right-to-left

I have some work to do in XeLaTeX, What's wrong with my code ?

What's I get :[image]

Any advice?

#### My MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}   

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x =y
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

(the problem goes away if one comments out amsmath and/or changes other language to a ltr language/comments out hebrew/arabic, whatever)  It must have something to do with how rtl languages are handled in conjunction with amsmath.

[image]

Comment: any solution ? I tried  bidi package,  LTR environment without success !